# upper confidence bound of a non-linear model seems wrong (predictNLS)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, nonlinear

I have the following data and R-script:

```
library(propagate)
xvalues<-c(0.92 , 3.00,  6.00 , 9.00 ,12.00 ,15.00, 18.00, 21.00, 24.00, 27.00)
yvalues<-c(210000000 ,210000000 ,200000000 ,180000000, 180000000, 180000000 ,160000000,160000000 ,160000000, 150000000)
data<-data.frame(xvalues,yvalues)

fit = nls(yvalues ~ SSasymp(xvalues, Asym, r0, lrc), data=data)
xCurve <- seq(0, 27, 1)
yCurve <- coef(fit)[1]+(coef(fit)[2]-coef(fit)[1])*exp(-exp(coef(fit)[3])*xCurve)

xnew<-seq(0,27,1)
pre<-predictNLS(fit, newdata=data.frame(xvalues=xnew), interval = c("confidence"))

CI_lower<-c()
for(i in 1:length(pre$prop)){CI_lower[i]<-pre$prop[[i]]$sim[5]}
CI_upper<-c()
for(i in 1:length(pre$prop)){CI_upper[i]<-pre$prop[[i]]$sim[6]}

plot(yvalues~xvalues,ylim=c(150000000,230000000))   
lines(xCurve, yCurve, col = 'green', lty = 1) 

lines(xnew,CI_lower,col="red")
lines(xnew,CI_upper,col="red")
```

[image]
Unfortunately, the confidence interval in the plot seems not to be correct. I think the lower confidence bound is fine, but the upper confidence bound looks strange. How to fix the problem? I want a upper confidence interval similar the lower one.

Answer (score 1):

I would [bootstrap the residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bootstrapping_(statistics)&oldid=861915794#Resampling_residuals):

```
fit = nls(yvalues ~ SSasymp(xvalues, Asym, r0, lrc), data=data)
xCurve <- seq(0, 27, 1)
yCurve <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(xvalues = xCurve))


library(boot)

set.seed(42)
#this is slow:
bootpred <- boot(data, function(df, i) {
  df$yvalues <- fitted(fit) + residuals(fit)[i] #bootstrap of residuals
  tryCatch({fit = nls(yvalues ~ SSasymp(xvalues, Asym, r0, lrc), data=df)
            predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(xvalues = xCurve))}, 
           error = function(e) xCurve * NA)
}, R = 1e4) #increase R (results in longer computing time) 

mean(is.na(bootpred$t[,1])) #4 % of fits failed, should hopefully be ok
CIpred <- apply(bootpred$t, 2, quantile, prob = c(0.025, 0.975), na.rm = TRUE)

plot(yvalues ~ xvalues, ylim = c(15e7,23e7))   
lines(yCurve ~ xCurve)
lines(CIpred["2.5%",] ~ xCurve, lty = 2)
lines(CIpred["97.5%",] ~ xCurve, lty = 2)
```

[image: resulting plot]